# create time series with a loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I have a question regarding a loop based setting for time series. I first load a data frame:

```
DataR <- read.csv("XXX/R_Input_CSVs/DataR.csv", sep=";")
```

I would like to use a loop to generate one time series of each column in DataR. My time series should have the name of the corresponding column:

```
Baugewerbe<-ts(DataR$Baugewerbe,freq=4,start=c(1991,3),end=c(2014,3))
Gastgewerbe<-ts(DataR$Gastgewerbe,freq=4,start=c(1991,3),end=c(2014,3))
Handel<-ts(DataR$Handel,freq=4,start=c(1991,3),end=c(2014,3))
```

...and so on

```
for(i in 1:ncol(DataR)){
names(DataR[i])<-ts(DataR[,i],freq=4,start=c(1991,3),end=c(2014,3))
}
```

Unfortunately the code doesn^t work. What do i have to change?
Thanks in advance

Comment: thanks akrun! it worked well with lapply!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try

```
list2env(setNames(lapply(DataR, function(x) 
    ts(x, freq=4, start=c(1991,3), end=c(2014,3)), names(DataR)), 
             envir=.GlobalEnv)
```